# Connect iPhone to MySql server without using web services

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c

I am new to IOS development, i am not able to connect my iPhone to mysql server. Is it possible to connect to mysql server without web services. I tried it in many ways. At last i found one post on http://macbug.org/macosxsample/mysql#.U-mq3oCSwni  about this topic but I am getting Apple Mach-0 linking error. I went through all the links related to this linking error, but i did not get specific answer. 
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked your posted link? It is related with `OSX` not `iOS`. And about your question, we can't connect iOS app with `MySql` directly, there should be a middle layer who does the talking between those two.

Comment: okay and middle layer means using web services?? thank u

Comment: Yes, middle layer means Web Services.